# Most pythonic way to index each tuple contained within a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

Sort of a Python beginner, sorry if this is a basic question.

I have tuples of the form (i, j) contained inside a list of variable length. This list is output by a function that is selecting clusters of pixels inside an image and averaging their RGB values, so the tuples are indices. The function is recursive, here is the return statement:

```
return ((red,blue,green), tuple_list, sum_n)
# [0] (r,g,b) values [1] list of indices as tuples [2] number of pixels gathered
```

I take the output from this function and write the new RGB values to my image matrix, which is a numpy array, like this by using a for loop:

```
cluster = rgb_avg_cluster(depth = 0, row = i, column = j, image = newimg)
    # cluster[1] is the list of tuple indices
    for x in cluster[1]: 
          newimg[x[0],x[1],0] = int(cluster[0][0])
          newimg[x[0],x[1],1] = int(cluster[0][1])
          newimg[x[0],x[1],2] = int(cluster[0][2])
```

My numpy array is [width, height, rgb], so for a 1200x600 image it would be (1200,600,3). Is there some quicker way to index the rgb values at each tuple index and change them to the new values?

As an example, if my output is `((150,40,40), [(35,35), (95,42)], 2)` is there a better/faster way to change pixels `(35,35)` and `(95,42)` in my numpy array to `rgb = (150,40,40)`? Like this:

```
input: 
        ((150,40,40), [(35,35), (95,42)], 2)

result: 
        newimg[35,35,0] = 150
        newimg[35,35,1] = 40
        newimg[35,35,2] = 40
        newimg[95,42,0] = 150
        newimg[95,42,1] = 40
        newimg[95,42,2] = 40
```

I know vectorized operations are the way to go with numpy but I don't know how to implement it in this case. This function takes a while to execute as-is.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using numpy, commit to it. There's hardly ever a need for lists. You can probably refactor your entire code to run much faster by not using lists in the image processing to begin with. In the meantime, look into fancy indexing.

Comment: That being said, please post an actual MCVE

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to avoid the iteration on the RGB dimension.  We still have to iterate on pixel indexing tuples:

```
In [10]: atup = ((150,40,40), [(35,35), (95,42)], 2)
In [11]: newimg = np.zeros((1200,600,3),int)
In [12]: vals = atup[0]
In [13]: idx = atup[1]
In [14]: for x in idx:
    ...:     newimg[x[0],x[1],:] = vals
    ...:
```

testing a few values:

```
In [15]: newimg[35,35,1]
Out[15]: 40
In [16]: newimg[95,42,2]
Out[16]: 40
```

Answer (score 0):

The first improvement is that when you call *rgb_avg_cluster*, save its
results decomposed into 3 components:

```
rgb, ind, sum_n = rgb_avg_cluster(...)
```

This way you avoid index access to the composite returned value (so far *cluster*).

Then you can save *rgb* into respective pixels e.g. in the following loop:

```
for r, c in ind:
    newimg[r, c, :] = rgb
```

To test the above code, I created a zero-filled array of size *2 rows*
by *4 columns* by *3 colors*:

```
newimg = np.zeros((2, 4, 3), dtype='int')
```

and set a "surrogate" *rgb_avg_cluster* result as:

```
rgb, ind, sum_n = ((150,40,40), [(1,1), (0,0)], 2)
```

After I ran the above loop, the result is:

```
array([[[150,  40,  40],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [150,  40,  40],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

## Edit

It is possible to save your results even without any explicit loop.

To perform a test on just the same array, run:

```
newimg = np.zeros((2, 4, 3), dtype='int')
rgb, ind, sum_n = ((150,40,40), [(1,1), (0,0)], 2)
ind2 = np.array(ind).T
newimg[ind2[0], ind2[1], :] = rgb
```

Details:

1. *ind2* contains an array with 2 rows:

   ```
    array([[1, 0],
           [1, 0]])
   ```

   The first row contains *x* coordinates of pixels to save, and the second
   row - *y* coordinates,
2. `newimg[ind2[0], ind2[1]]` - provides access to the indicated pixels.
   *ind2[0]* specifies *x* coordinates and *ind2[1]* - *y* coordinates.
   The third index is actually not needed. You access all elements in
   this dimension, just like you wrote "*, :*" (as the third index).
3. `newimg[...] = rgb` - saves *rgb* at the given indices, **in one go**.